# How does Xbox Game Bar & Xbox Console Companion resolve game invites?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, windows-11, protocol-handler, xbox-game-dvr

When being invited to a game by a friend, Xbox Game Bar (and previously) Xbox Console Companion need to be able to launch the application when you accept the invite.

On my computer I have 2 copies of Sea of Thieves installed, one MS Store, and one Steam.

Xbox Console Companion launches the 'correct' one which IMO is the MS Store.

Xbox Game Bar launches the 'incorrect' one which is the Steam copy.

It would seem that these 2 applications are using 2 different resolution methods, to work out which copy of the game to run.

By what mechanism is each of these applications using to resolve the installed games?

DLL Registration? Registry Keys? Protocol Registration registered to the applications?

Comment: If you uninstall the Steam copy, and then launch the game with the Game Bar, does it work?

Comment: I can't recall off the top of my head, the apps have iterated fairly fast, and at times prompted to reinstall steam, or worked correctly until the steam copy is reinstalled. Basically I need to be able to switch when I want, without having to juggle installations constantly. Thus, the question is about the mechanics, and not the fix.

Comment: I was suggesting you try to do exactly that. The Steam version shouldn’t be launching with those applications, the Steam version, should be launched when you turn the shortcut

Comment: Can we keep it on topic? " The Steam version shouldn’t be launching with those applications," For some users this would be entirely correct behavior. The question is about the mechanics, not the solution to my (simplified) problem which was only included for context.

Comment: Remotely diagnosing the issue, and then figuring out how the two applications work, is sort of difficult.  I had additional thoughts on the matter but was trying to get a baseline. I won’t be able to help you without that baseline. The next step after you confirmed with the baseline was to then reinstall the Steam version and see which versions the applications launched.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Answer:**

**Game Bar, Non MSStore Games:**

For non MSStore games, GameBar has a collection of registry keys based on the internal Xbox TitleID.

`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\XboxLive`

Contains hives named by the the title id.

e.g. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\XboxLive\804980065` corresponds to Sea of Thieves Insider.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\XboxLive\1717113201` corresponds to Sea of Thieves.

Inside these registry nodes, is a protocol reference that is executed when this override / external game key is present.

`AcceptProtocol` = `steam://run/1172630//?cmd=accept_{1}_{2}_{0}`

and

`JoinProtocol` = `steam://run/1172630//?cmd=join_{2}_{1}_{0}`

Presumably, Accept is used when an invite is accepted, and Join Protocol is initiated when a game is joined without invitation.

The ID in the steam:// protocol is the *steam* appid of the title.

**Game Bar, MSStore Game:**

**Xbox Console Companion, MSStore Game:**

**Xbox Console Companion, Non MSStore Game:**

I believe this is unsupported.