# cannot connect through game bar to sea of thieves via windows 11

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11, regedit, protocol-handler, xbox-game-dvr

[image]

I have Steam Sea of Thieves. I have always connected to friends through game bar, right-click the friend, join game. I want this to work, not a workaround. It worked up until a new PC I just swapped to.

Yes, the accounts are linked and my privacy settings are right. Yes I have gamebar and the xbox windows apps installed and updated. Yes, I tried repair and refresh on them. I have tried all the troubleshooting I can find in every other similar post about this issue. Help!

I have also done an upgrade-in-place of windows 11.

I get the "ms-xbl-multiplayer" error.

I am on Windows 11.

I do not have the registry folder for xboxlive at all as described here (my old PC does): [How does Xbox Game Bar & Xbox Console Companion resolve game invites?](https://superuser.com/questions/1707619/how-does-xbox-game-bar-xbox-console-companion-resolve-game-invites)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the error message, I'm not familiar with it. I think the location of the registry hive may have changed. Let me boot up my PC and check.

Comment: I cannot at the moment because no one is online for me to test joining to, but i found the image in another language same message, added to post above.

Comment: How did you install windows? I assume you have the various xbox services installed, and haven't used a non-official distribution that rips out all the MS tracking etc? It's plausible that such a distribution would have removed, damaged or disabled the mechanisms that Xbox Live uses.

Comment: I don't have windows 11, but it's possible the location that the registry key moved or something? The way you could find the expected location on windows 11, is to use something like process monitor to find what registry keys are accessed when joining a friend from sea of thieves.

Comment: Typically, the registry keys in question get re-planted every time sea of thieves steam edition boots up, on my machine, on windows 10.